# Can 't fecth content whit query.ID in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I 'm traying to find out what I'm doing wrong in this code but y can't resolve it.
I need to use my query.id inside getInitialPops to fecth some contents. The fetch works, but in my catch i recives this error:

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://url/resume-true.json reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

The original endpoint its:

```
https://url/resume-${query.id}.json
```

and when I console.log the query.id returns, first

```
slug-5 (this is the rigth one)
```

and second:

```
true (I dont'know were this came from)
```

This is my getInitialProps

```
channelRouter.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  console.log("query**", query.id);
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://url/resume-${query.id}.json`
    );
    let data = await res.json();
    return { data };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`${e}`);
  }
};
```

Any idea?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error many times before.

`FetchError: invalid json response body at https://url/resume-true.json reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

This means that your endpoint is returning HTML instead of JSON (hence the start with `<`)

Check your endpoint, it's not valid json, could be a 404 or 500 status in html

Comment: Thank you Peter, but I alrready check and the format of the json its okey..

Comment: Can you check it with chrome developer tools- network traffic?